# Length of the data to decrypt is invalid when decrypting

Tags: c#, image, encryption

I need to encrypt an image, return the string of the encrypted data, then decrypt it

Here's my encryption code :

```
string plainText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Imagebytes);
byte[] encrypted;
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4");;
// Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object 
using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    aesAlg.Key = key;
    aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;

    // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

    // Create the streams used for encryption. 
    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {

                //Write all data to the stream.
                swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
            }
            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();

        }
    }
}

using (var aesAlg = new AesManaged())
{


    aesAlg.Key = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4");
    aesAlg.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(Imagebytes, 0, Imagebytes.Length)).Length;

}
```

My decryption work fine ( because i can receive image / video perfectly )

here's the code:

```
const  string BLOB_KEY = "TTAyY25RNTFKaTk3dndUNA==";
using (RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged())
{
    rm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    rm.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(BLOB_KEY);
    rm.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    rm.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rm.CreateDecryptor(),
                    CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my encryption code ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking specifically. Do you decrypt the data you have encrypted yourself and you do not get the same plaintext as you had before? And you are talking about images and videos - what have they to do with your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your very initial line of code is already wrong:

```
string plainText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Imagebytes);
```

An image is not a string, and plaintext is not necessarily a string either. Both consist of bytes. So you should not be using a `StreamWriter` either, just a normal stream.

It is likely that data is lost during conversion.

Furthermore, you are writing to a decryption stream and you are using ECB mode at one side and CBC mode at the other.

I would strongly advice you to read into the material and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i've changed my code to :

```
var aesAlg = new AesManaged
        {
            KeySize = 128,
            Key = key,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
            Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
            IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        return encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(Imagebytes, 0, Imagebytes.Length);
```

And it works fine !